# Не запускается виртуальная машина Linux

Tags: linux, debian, hyper-v

Сегодня перестала запускаться виртуальная машина Debian, видимо из-за того, что была выключена жестко.

```
[ 0.017798] Spectre V2 : LFENCE not serializing. Switching to generic retpoline
[ 0.756189] piix4_smbus 0000:00:07.3: SMBus base address uninitialized - upgrade BIOS or use force_addr=0xaddr
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Подскажи пожалуйста, можно ли как-то тут что-то сделать?
Сервер очень важен, он находится на Hyper-V, есть бекап машины, но довольно старый(

Comment: recovering journal то чем заканчивается или ещё идёт?

Comment: нужно подождать окончания работы fsck

Comment: Идёт уже долго, и ничего не происходит…

Comment: в гипевизоре видна работа с диском? диск большой? если активности за 5 минут не было, сделай ещё одну перезагрузку

Comment: Спасибо вам за советы, всё сейчас работает.

Answer (score 0):

Оказалось, что неисправен процессор у сервера.
На другом сервере виртуальная машина запустилась без проблем.